# Missed scheduled WordPress

Tags: wp-cron, scheduled-posts

I am currently in version 3.1 of WordPress and I have a problem with planning my post. In fact, whenever I plan a post, it is written: "Scheduled missed. Could you help me please.

Comment: A similar question is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13673/missed-schedule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to your server configuration, you may need to use the alternate cron method, which uses redirect rather than http loopback.

Try adding the following to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
// Alternate cron method 
define( 'ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true );
```

Comment: Well, this does work for me. But I don't think I could use it in a production environment. Before you all go rushing to add this line of code check this out http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/ALTERNATE-WP-CRON-Is-it-worth-it-td39843.html

Answer (score -6):

The missed schedule is due to wordpress timeout in the cron process. 
Go to wp-include/cron.php, around line no 248, change the value of 0.01 to a larger number.

in my case, I changed from :
wp_remote_post( $cron_url, array( 'timeout' => 0.01, 'blocking' => false, 'sslverify' => apply_filters( 'https_local_ssl_verify', true ) ) );

to

wp_remote_post( $cron_url, array( 'timeout' => 7, 'blocking' => false, 'sslverify' => apply_filters( 'https_local_ssl_verify', true ) ) );

remember this cron.php is a wordpress core file, it will get overwritten when you update your wordpress core. So after every update, remember to change the value again.

If this doesn't work for you, make sure your timezone setting is set correctly. The setting can be found at:
Settings > General

Comment: No - do NOT change core files - if you do, when you upgrade WP, your change will be lost.

Comment: -1 for hacking core.  See the accepted answer.

Comment: -10000 for hacking core. Don't hack core, even if you find no other solution (which is highly unlikely)

Comment: That 0.01 second timeout is there for a reason! The WP-cron call happens in the background and you don't want your code to halt on that. 

And also: you never hack into core files!